# How to prevent over-posting with UseSqlServer vs UseInMemoryDatabase?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

Following the [tutorial on creating a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), with the [tutorial's project files](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/first-web-api/samples/7.0/TodoApiDTO) for reference, I created the exact project described with the DTO approach, which worked successfully using an in-memory database:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
```

Now I want to achieve the same outcome using a SQL Server database instead.

So instead of using `opt.UseInMemoryDatabase`, I'm now using `opt.UseSqlServer(<MY-CONNECTION-STRING>)` in its place. This is the only line of code that I have changed from the tutorial.

I set up a SQL Server with a table for `TodoItems` with 3 columns named `Id`, `Name` and `IsComplete`, which matches the names of the `TodoItemDTO` class fields.

The problem I am experiencing with the SQL Server is that the program is trying to post the `Secret` field from the `TodoItem` object.

I get this exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Secret'.

Why does the DTO approach described in the tutorial work for an in-memory database but not with a SQL Server database?

Comment: Your choice of persistence store has absolutely nothing to do with overposting attacks: the proper way to avoid overposting is to not re-use EF entity types as DTOs. Define DTOs separately from EF classes. Just because a DTO type and an Entity type will inevitably share many member properties, that does not make them interchangeable or substitutable.

Comment: _"Why does the DTO approach described in the tutorial work for an in-memory database but not with a SQL Server database"_ - because the InMemoryDatabase implementation used by EF does not enforce schemas.

Comment: Have you created migration and applied it to the SQL database after adding new field?

Answer (score 0):

The in-memory implementation does not behave the same as a real SQL server. There is a statement made in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/#involving-the-database-or-not which suggests:

> The in-memory provider will not behave like your real database in many important ways. Some features cannot be tested with it at all (e.g. transactions, raw SQL..), while other features may behave differently than your production database (e.g. case-sensitivity in queries). While in-memory can work for simple, constrained query scenarios, it is highly limited and we discourage its use.

Answer (score -1):

Because table TodoItems not has column 'Secret'. 
I think table was define before. 
you can use migrate to add new column or ignore mapping that column.

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoItem
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string? Secret { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because what you're suggesting will not solve the OP's problem, and in-fact, will break their existing database by now _removing_ the `Secret` column that EF generated. The _real_ solution is to not re-use EF entity types (like this `class TodoItem` for Web API DTOs): they should define a new, separate types: `class NewTodoItemRequestDto`  and `TodoItemResponseDto` - separate types are needed because `NewTodoItemRequestDto` won't have an `Id` value, and `TodoItemResponseDto` _will_ have an `Id` value, but _both_ types must not expose the `Secret` value.